# Unable to remove package from Delphi 2005

Tags: delphi

I needed to reinstall a package, DrRX.bpl. I removed it from the package list, and trying to install a newer version of the same package. I've replaced the old component's dir with the new one.

When I open the new DrRX.bpl and click install, I get the error

"Package C:\Program Files\Borland\BDS\3.0\components\rx work\output\DrRx.bpl cannot be installed because another package with the same basename is already loaded (DrRx.bpl)"

I cannot find any reference to DrRX in my package list, DrRX does not appear in the Tool Palette. How do I locate where Delphi thinks this is installed, and remove it, so I can reinstall the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have an entry for this in your "Known Package" entry in your registry that is, for whatever reason, not working correctly.

Close RAD Studio.
Run REGEDIT.EXE and then go to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\RADStudio\8.0\Known Packages

And see if there is an entry for DrRX.bpl.  If there is, remove it, and try to install again.

Comment: Thanks, there was no mention of DrRx.bpl in the Known Packages key, but this did point me to the right direction.

I searched for DrRX in the registry and removed any mention of it, then it worked.

Comment: Which Delphi release uses Embarcadero\RADStudio\8.0 ?

Comment: Whoops!  I did manage to change from our internal name to "RADStudio":-)

Answer (score 3):

What I have experienced myself many times is that after removing a package from the IDE, a reference remains in the `Package Cache` registry key under the Delphi registry key (e.g. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\CodeGear\BDS\7.0 for Delphi 2010).  Though the package is no longer visible in the IDE, trying to install another package with the same name or a package containing a component with the same name causes errors until I delete the package that I uninstalled from the `Package Cache` registry key.  It seems the cache is a bit too persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search the whole HD for others? Try that.  If you find one, try to move/delete it. If you can't, then Delphi has got it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Delphi has got it"? I searched and only one found is the one I want to install.

Comment: "got it" = file in use. But if there's only one, then this is probably a dead end. Go with Nick's suggestion....